# R: simulate time series data that follows AR(1) 1000 trials

Tags: r

I want a way I can simulate a time-series data that follows the autoregressive model of order one AR(1) not just once but 1000 times such that it will output the average of 1000 tries to form the final output as just a series. The following **MWE** demonstrate just a single trial:

```
n <- 15
a <- 0.5
e <- rnorm(n+100)
x <- double(n+100)
x[1] <- rnorm(1)
for(i in 2:(n+100)) {
  x[i] <- a * x[i-1] + e[i]
}
x <- ts(x[-(1:100)])
```

Why I want this is that when the time series sample is small it does not tend to the parameter specified. I think of having some repeated trials up to 1000 times; such that the first sample of all of the 1000 trials are averaged and made to be the first sample of the series, so is the second up to the 1000th sample.

With the above I know the final time-series data that will be 15 will converge to an AR(1) with `a=0.5`. but I do not know how to do it the 1000 times and average them in `R`.

Comment: can you tell me what you expected of this question that you are not getting instead of the down vote?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `arima.sim` to simulate data from an ARIMA model. We can then wrap `arima.sim` in a `replicate` loop and average data using `rowMeans`; here is a reproducible example where we generate 1000 time series (each consisting of 100 time points) from an AR(1) model.

```
set.seed(2020)
n <- 100
mat <- replicate(1000, arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = 0.5)))
```

This will return a `100x1000` matrix. We can now calculate the row average and store the resulting object as a `ts` timeseries object.

```
ts <- as.ts(rowMeans(mat))

library(forecast)
autoplot(ts)
```

[image]